# Склонение иракского имени

Tags: склонение-фамилий, имена

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять по падежам иракское имя Ал - Канаани Абан Ахмед Али? Понимаю, что фамилия Ал-Канаани не склоняется. А как быть с остальными частями имени?

Comment: *Ал - Канаани* или *Ал-Канаани*? Отличать не гадая хотелось бы, где тире, а где дефис.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну так это опечатка. И дело не только в дефисе (Ал-Канаани), дело в том, что не Ал, а Аль.

Аль-Канаани Абан Ахмед Али.

Склоняются имена Абан и Ахмед. Что, всё падежи рисовать?! О_о

И. Аль-Канаани Абан Ахмед Али

Р. Аль-Канаани Абана Ахмеда Али.

Д. Аль-Канаани Абану Ахмеду Али.

В. Аль-Канаани Абана Ахмеда Али.

Т. Аль-Канаани Абаном Ахмедом Али.

П. Аль-Канаани Абане Ахмеде Али.